# Connecting to WLAN freezes system on Asus eee pc 1001p

Tags: 11.04, eeepc, wireless, asus

This might be a quite old problem, however I couldn't find a solution for myself.
I was using Ubuntu 10.10 on my Asus eee pc 1001p until I upgraded to Natty. Now, whenever I connect to a password secured wireless network, the system freezes and needs to be hard rebooted.

It looks like this 'bug' affects the whole eee-family. In [this topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1741593) on ubuntuforums, the user 'linux_one' states, that an update to the latest daily mainline kernel from the kernel-ppa would solve the issue. Unfortunately, this didn't prove true for me. My system is also up-to-date right now.

I doubt, that the problem lies in the kernel itself, since the wlan-drivers already caused trouble in the past. I've been using the wireless fixes on http://linuxon1001p.blogspot.com so far.

Any solution or hint is appreciated. I'll give additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it on my own! :D

As I wrote above, the solution of 'linux_one' in the ubuntuforums didn't work out for me, since the image.deb wouldn't install properly. But her/his solution was right after all.

So this is how I stopped the WLAN from crashing my system:

1. Go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/
2. Download the following files:

   - linux-headers-3.0.0-999-generic_3.0.0-999.201106141052_i386.deb
   - linux-headers-3.0.0-999_3.0.0-999.201106141052_all.deb
   - linux-image-3.0.0-999-generic_3.0.0-999.201106141052_i386.deb

   (or the newer files, depending on the date of your download)
3. And download this file: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/73208056/module-init-tools_3.13-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
4. Install gdebi, a graphical installer for deb files
5. Open Gdebi (press [Alt]+[F2], type 'gdebi-gtk' and press enter)
6. With Gdebi open and install the downloaded linux-**headers** of step 2
7. Install the module-init-tools of step 3 using gdebi
8. Install the linux-**image** of step 2 with gdebi
9. Reboot your system. It should automatically boot the new kernel.

And that did the trick for me. Special thanks to 'linux_one' and 'nighthawk77' of ubuntuforums, who did the heavy work on this solution.